# How do I add ngx_pagespeed to elastic beanstalk?

Tags: nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

I have an Elastic Beanstalk environment running nginx 1.6.2
Anyone know how to install the ngx_pagespeed module into this? The [web instructions](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source) suggest re-building nginx, but I fear of losing the currently Amazon configured nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Do a post deployment hooks to install the ngx_pagespeed in elastic beanstalk server as like below,

Create a fiel of folder path ***.platform/hooks/postdeploy/01_ngx_pagespeed.sh***

and add the below code

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo "Installing Ngx Pagespeed"
sudo apt-get install build-essential zlib1g-dev libpcre3 libpcre3-dev unzip uuid-dev
echo "exiting.."
```